# Convert string data to pdf

Tags: android, kotlin, pdf

I have an Object that I receive by a request to a service.

Object:

"filename":"conclusions.pdf"
"file":"JVBERi0xLjQKJdPr6eEKMSAwIG9iago8PC9DcmVhdG9yIChDaHJvbWl1bSkKL1Byb2R1Y2VyIChTa2lhL1BERiBtODEpCi9DcmVhdGlvbkRhdGUgKEQ6MjAyMTEwMjcxODE5NTMrMDAnMDAnKQovTW9kRGF0ZSAoRDoyMDIxMTAyNzE4MTk1MyswMCcwMCcpPj4KZW5kb2JqCjMgMCBvYmoKPDwvY2EgMQovQk0gL05vcm1"}

I want to convert the file string to a readable pdf and save it in a temporal directory and get his path, how could I do that? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: If that is a base64 encoded pdf file than it is a very small pdf. What is in it?

Comment: Use android.graphics.pdf.PdfDocument https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument

Comment: `save it in a temporal directory and get his path,` ?? What do you mean? If you wanna save something then you should first have a path. Then save.